# Convert cURL command Into Python using requests

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

I am trying to convert the following cULR command into Python:

```
curl --location --request POST 'api.datamyne.com/frontend/REST/application' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "token": "boKnofR06mzldz5eL00ARwa3B9winzpn",
  "idApp":44
}'
```

I have the following Python code, but does not seem to work. Any idea how to include the raw data into into the request?

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'token': 'boKnofR06mzldz5eL00ARwa3B9winzpn',
    'idApp': '44'
}

response = requests.get('http://api.datamyne.com/frontend/REST/applications', headers=headers)

print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So in your python example you have called `request.get()`.

If you call `request.post()` it will instead become a POST request.

as for adding it to the body, you could try a `body` variable:

```
data =  {
    'token': 'boKnofR06mzldz5eL00ARwa3B9winzpn',
    'idApp': '44'
}

response = requests.post('http://api.datamyne.com/frontend/REST/applications',
                          headers=headers,
                          data = data)
```

Update:
This still fails because of an incorrectly formatted body.

to fix this i imported the `json` package and wrote:

```
#load string into a json object
data =  json.loads('{"token": "boKnofR06mzldz5eL00ARwa3B9winzpn", "idApp": 44 }')

# json.dumps outputs a json object to a string.
response = requests.post('https://api.datamyne.com/frontend/REST/application', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Thanks! the request seems better formatted, however, I am still getting an error (400 response) with Python using your code whereas with cURL the response is correct (202 response). Any idea why?

Comment: The only other thing that i can see is that you are going to a different url in the cURL as apposed to the requests package.

curl = `api.datamyne.com/frontend/REST/application`

requests = `http://api.datamyne.com/frontend/REST/applications`http://api.datamyne.com/frontend/REST/applications

Maybe try removing s to the end of application

Comment: Okay. So i got it to work by using json to format the body. I will update my answer.

Comment: you can bypass all the json stuff by using the json param to requests
```data = {"token": "boKnofR06mzldz5eL00ARwa3B9winzpn", "idApp": 44 }```
```response = requests.post('https://api.datamyne.com/frontend/REST/application', headers=headers, json=data)```